# Asp.net Mvc5 create different areas with same model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a project with no area. 
Now I would like to create an admin section and I would like to use the same model already present. 
It's possible? How?
Thanks

Comment: Areas have nothing to do with models.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to know which is the most correct method to use: create 2 areas (admin and user) and leave the model outside these 2 areas, or create only an area for admin and refer to the EF model (MyModel.edmx)  already present? I apologize but I have put the question badly